# Xpath or Css expression that will match with or without a class or id name?

Tags: css, xpath

Say you want to find `h1` elements with the xpath expression

```
//h1[@class="bold"]
```

Is there a way to make it so that it will also match `h1` without the exact class name in one expression? Even ones without any class.

What would the css equivalent look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this...

```
//h1[not(@class and contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " bold "))]
```

The overly complicated `contains()` predicate is to match the `bold` class name if it appears in the space-delimited list of class names the `class` attribute may contain.

A CSS selector may be simpler but I'm not very good with those. You could try

```
h1:not(.bold)
```

jsFiddle ~ http://jsfiddle.net/ow0fdtbv/1/

Comment: oh man that looks really complicated. what would a css path look like? would it be any cleaner? what if the h1 doesn't have any class attribute at all?

Comment: The "no class attribute" scenario is handled by the `not(@class ...` part

Comment: @user299709 I've added a CSS selector to my answer that should work and looks much simpler

Comment: the css path looks miles cleaner. but wouldn't that just select h1 without bold as class name? or does the . have a special meaning

Comment: The CSS selector will select all `<h1>` elements that do not have a `.bold` class in their class list.

Comment: @user299709 I've added a jsFiddle demo to illustrate the CSS selector

Comment: what if you want the xpath to select any `h1` with any class or no class at all? Basically a catch all expression. maybe `//h1[not(@class="bold") or @class="bold"] ?`

Comment: @user299709 If you wanted to select any `<h1>` with any class or no class, simple use `//h1`. Unless you mean something else, it sounds like you just don't want to use any predicate

Comment: hmm I see. basically I was thinking of a situation where the class name could be varied slightly like `bold-2492` but I think that is too crazy